# How to use correlation function?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation

If I have a normal distribution and some autocorrelation function $\rho(\tau) = Exp[-\tau/\xi]$.
Where $\xi$ is a correlation length, $\tau$ is a lag.

How to use it? Does it mean $Correlation({\tau}_{0},{\tau}_{1})$ need to be always greater than  $\rho(\tau)$? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autocorrelation can be performed on any time series, and in general, the value of the autocorrelation function will depend on times $\tau_1, \tau_2$ explicitly. If the value depends only on lag, then the corresponding time series must be at least weakly stationary. You seem to have one of those. One example of an autocorrelation function is the one you gave: $exp(-\Delta \tau/\xi)$, where $\xi$ is the correlation *time*. This exponential decay is a property of time series with an autoregressive component, $p>0$ in the ARIMA $(p,d,q)$ model.

This is a broad statistical feature of the time series. It holds on average. It does not mean $x(\tau_2)-\mu=(x(\tau_1)-\mu) exp(-|\tau_2-\tau_1|/\xi)$, but it does mean $E(x(\tau_2)-\mu)=(x(\tau_1)-\mu) exp(-|\tau_2-\tau_1|/\xi)$ after averaging over the zero-mean noise, which is additive at every step in the time series. Here $\mu=E(x(\tau))=constant.$

You refer to $Correlation(\tau_1,\tau_2)$, giving explicit times. Under the condition of stationary, this would not be a function of the times, but the lag. The only other possible confusion I sense is that your definition of $Correlation$ may or may not involve $\mu$. Certainly the ACF $\rho$ does subtract the long-time average value $\mu$ from all numbers, per the requirements of autocorrelation.